# How to show name specific tag in shopify

Tags: ruby, shopify, product

I want to display the value of a specific product tag in my shopify store.

The product tag always starts with **Color_** followed by the color **Color_Green**

I want to display only green. (I can use split or slice for that part)

But I can't figure out to only display the tag that starts with Color_  because I have multiple tags added to my products.

This is my code for now:

`{%- for tag in product.tags -%} {%- assign tag_prefix = tag %} {%- if tag_prefix == "Color_" -%} {%- endif -%} {%- endfor -%}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet

```
{% for tag in product.tags %}
    {% assign tag_prefix = tag %}
    {% if tag_prefix contains "Color_" %}
        {% assign tagValue = tag_prefix | replace: "Color_", "" %}
        {{ tagValue }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```